# Azure Digital Twin Explorer. How do you query for total number of e.g. nodes (something like COUNT())

Tags: count, azure-digital-twins

In ADT Explorer, it seems you should simply be able to do: SELECT COUNT() FROM DIGITALTWINS... to get the number of hits for a given query. However, I keep getting 'The query returned results that could not be displayed or overlayed', presumably because its set up to return nodes, properties etc. and not a single integer as with a functional query like COUNT().
Any help explaining how to display the total number of hits on screen would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit the settings icon and enable the output screen in the top right.
[image: Screenshot of the settings screen]

After that, the raw response of your query will be shown in the output screen. For instance, the output of your query:

```json
Requested query: SELECT COUNT() FROM DIGITALTWINS
Ran query for twins, page 1:
{
  "queryCharge": 2.99,
  "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'none'",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "date": "Mon, 12 Dec 2022 12:35:07 GMT",
  "mise-correlation-id": "69ed1cf9-df16-4026-a6fb-0d1cf4ae7bc6",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=2592000",
  "traceresponse": "00-e969f89deecb09057f2d02ca3c5eddf9-5dc77084297ae15c-01",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "x-powered-by": "Express",
  "value": [
    {
      "COUNT": 8
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": null
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: not pretty is good enough, thanks very much!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped and your query is resolved. So others can benefit from it to identify the answer easily.